# How can I pause slider on hover?

Tags: javascript, slider

I have an API small learning project. Where I get image from calling the API then I select some images to create a slideshow in chosen interval.
Now **I want to pause the slideshow when I mouseover(hover) it.** **But I don't understand how to do it. If you guys can help me. That will be very great. Below are my code.**
My live site link : https://muradtheoz.github.io/fancy-slider/
my repo link: [github repo](https://github.com/muradtheOZ/fancy-slider)
and below are my row code

```js
 

   const imagesArea = document.querySelector('.images');
const gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery');
const galleryHeader = document.querySelector('.gallery-header');
const searchBtn = document.getElementById('search-btn');
const sliderBtn = document.getElementById('create-slider');
const sliderContainer = document.getElementById('sliders');
const inputField = document.getElementById('search');
const durationField = document.getElementById('duration');
// selected image 
let sliders = [];


// If this key doesn't work
// Find the name in the url and go to their website
// to create your own api key
const KEY = '15674931-a9d714b6e9d654524df198e00&q';

// show images 
const showImages = (images) => {
  imagesArea.style.display = 'block';
  gallery.innerHTML = '';
  // show gallery title
  galleryHeader.style.display = 'flex';
  images.forEach(image => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-item mb-2';
    div.innerHTML = ` <img class="img-fluid img-effect img-thumbnail" onclick=selectItem(event,"${image.webformatURL}") src="${image.webformatURL}" alt="${image.tags}">`;
    gallery.appendChild(div);
  })
  toggleSpinner();

}

const getImages = (query) => {
  toggleSpinner();
  dangerInfo(false);

  imagesArea.style.display = 'none';
  const url = (`https://pixabay.com/api/?key=${KEY}=${query}&image_type=photo&pretty=true`);

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if ((data.hits).length > 0) {

        showImages(data.hits);
      }
      else {
        imagesArea.style.display = 'none';
        dangerInfo(true);
        toggleSpinner();

      }

    })
    .catch(err => dangerInfo(true))
}

let slideIndex = 0;
const selectItem = (event, img) => {
  let element = event.target;
  element.classList.add('added');
  element.classList.remove('img-effect')

  let item = sliders.indexOf(img);
  if (item === -1) {
    sliders.push(img);
  } else {
    // sliders.pop(img);
    sliders.splice(item, 1);
    element.classList.toggle("added");
    element.classList.toggle('img-effect')
  }
}
var timer
const createSlider = () => {
  // check slider image length
  if (sliders.length < 2) {
    alert('Select at least 2 image.')
    return;
  }
  // crate slider previous next area
  sliderContainer.innerHTML = '';
  const prevNext = document.createElement('div');
  prevNext.className = "prev-next d-flex w-100 justify-content-between align-items-center";
  prevNext.innerHTML = ` 
  <span class="prev" onclick="changeItem(-1)"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
  <span class="next" onclick="changeItem(1)"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
  `;

  sliderContainer.appendChild(prevNext)
  document.querySelector('.main').style.display = 'block';
  // hide image aria
  imagesArea.style.display = 'none';
  let duration = document.getElementById('duration').value || 1000;
  if (duration <= 400) {
    duration = 1000;
    if (confirm("slider duration will set to 1s default")) {
      sliders.forEach(slide => {
        let item = document.createElement('div')
        item.className = "slider-item";
        item.innerHTML = `<img class="w-100"
        src="${slide}"
        alt="">`;
        sliderContainer.appendChild(item)
      })
      changeSlide(0)
      timer = setInterval(function () {
        slideIndex++;
        changeSlide(slideIndex);
      }, duration);

    }
    else {
      imagesArea.style.display = 'block';

    }

  }

  else {

    sliders.forEach(slide => {
      let item = document.createElement('div')
      item.className = "slider-item";
      item.innerHTML = `<img class="w-100"
      src="${slide}"
      alt="">`;
      sliderContainer.appendChild(item)
    })
    changeSlide(0)
    timer = setInterval(function () {
      slideIndex++;
      changeSlide(slideIndex);
    }, duration);

  }

}

// change slider index 
const changeItem = index => {
  changeSlide(slideIndex += index);
}

// change slide item
const changeSlide = (index) => {

  const items = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-item');
  if (index < 0) {
    slideIndex = items.length - 1
    index = slideIndex;
  };

  if (index >= items.length) {
    index = 0;
    slideIndex = 0;
  }

  items.forEach(item => {
    item.style.display = "none"
  })

  items[index].style.display = "block"
}

function getInputValue() {
  document.querySelector('.main').style.display = 'none';
  clearInterval(timer);
  const search = document.getElementById('search');
  getImages(search.value)
  sliders.length = 0;
}

const triggerSearchBtn = inputField.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {

  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    getInputValue();
  }

})

durationField.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {

  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    createSlider()
  }
})

//Bonus Marking javascript
const toggleSpinner = () => {
  const spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');
  spinner.classList.toggle('d-flex');
}

const dangerInfo = (show) => {
  const error = document.getElementById('error');

  if (show) {
    error.classList.add('d-flex');
  }
  else {
    error.classList.remove('d-flex');
  }

}


sliderContainer.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  e.target.style.display = "block";

});

sliderContainer.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
  sliderContainer.style.border = '6px solid #1e1743';
});
```

```css
  #sliders {
  height: 400px;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery-header {
  display: none;
}

.slider-item {
  display: none;
}

.img-thumbnail {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.added {
  border: 2px solid #1e1743;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

img {
  height: 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.prev-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev, .next {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.dot {
  background-color: rgb(163, 156, 156);
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.main {
  display: none;
}
/*bonus css style*/
.img-effect:hover{
  background-color: #1e1743;

}


/*input arrow hide style*/
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
/* .slider-item :hover{
  display: none;
} */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .justify-content-around.align-items-center.mt-3.gallery-header.mb-2 {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #sliders {
    height: 300px;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Slide your favorite images</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h4 class="mt-2 text-center">Search Image for create slider</h4>
    <div class="form-inline mt-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="input-group col-md-6 mb-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="nature">
      </div>
      <button onclick="getInputValue()" type="button" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Search</button>
    </div>
    <!--bonus content-->
  </div>
  <div id="spinner" class="justify-content-center p-2 d-none">
    <div class="spinner-border text-info" role="status">
      <span class="visually-hidden"> </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="error" class="justify-content-center p-2 d-none">
    <div class="card text-white bg-danger mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-header text-center">We Are sorry</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">The image your searching is not available</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <section class="images">
    <div class="justify-content-around align-items-center mt-3 gallery-header mb-2">
      <h3 class="head-title text-center">Select image for create slider</h3>
      <div class="input-group col-md-3 mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <input type="number" class="form-control arrow-hide" id="duration" placeholder="slider change duration">
      </div>
      <button onclick=" createSlider()" id="create-slider" class="btn btn-primary px-5">Create slider</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row gallery">

  </section>
  <!-- slider -->
  <div class="main">
    <section class="mt-5" id="sliders">

    </section>
    <div class="dots d-flex mt-2 w-100 justify-content-center align-items-center bg-light">
      <span class="dot" onclick="changeItem(-1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="changeItem(1)"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add mouseenter event (equivalent of hover in events terms) listener on slider's parent element (some parent). Inside of listener callback clear timeout of sliding function. I can code it for you if you need implementation help. Let me know wheter you do

Comment: Thanks @PythonicSpeaker . I will try to implement it now. If fail to do it then I will inform you in comment

Comment: @PythonicSpeaker please help me with code snippet . I tried but failed.

Comment: ok. wait please and I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following version of your **app.js** does the trick.

```
const imagesArea = document.querySelector('.images');
const gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery');
const galleryHeader = document.querySelector('.gallery-header');
const searchBtn = document.getElementById('search-btn');
const sliderBtn = document.getElementById('create-slider');
const sliderContainer = document.getElementById('sliders');
const inputField = document.getElementById('search');
// selected image 
let sliders = [];
// Initial value
let lastSetDuration = 0;


// If this key doesn't work
// Find the name in the url and go to their website
// to create your own api key
const KEY = '15674931-a9d714b6e9d654524df198e00&q';

// show images 
const showImages = (images) => {
  imagesArea.style.display = 'block';
  gallery.innerHTML = '';
  // show gallery title
  galleryHeader.style.display = 'flex';
  images.forEach(image => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-item mb-2';
    div.innerHTML = ` <img class="img-fluid img-effect img-thumbnail" onclick=selectItem(event,"${image.webformatURL}") src="${image.webformatURL}" alt="${image.tags}">`;
    gallery.appendChild(div);
  })
  toggleSpinner();

}

const getImages = (query) => {
    toggleSpinner();
    dangerInfo(false);
    
    imagesArea.style.display = 'none';
    const url = (`https://pixabay.com/api/?key=${KEY}=${query}&image_type=photo&pretty=true`);

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if ((data.hits).length > 0) {

        showImages(data.hits);
      }
      else {
        imagesArea.style.display = 'none';
        dangerInfo(true);
        toggleSpinner();

      }



    })
    .catch(err => dangerInfo(true))
}

let slideIndex = 0;
const selectItem = (event, img) => {
  let element = event.target;
  element.classList.add('added');
  element.classList.remove('img-effect')

  let item = sliders.indexOf(img);
  if (item === -1) {
    sliders.push(img);
  } else {
    // sliders.pop(img);
    sliders.splice(item, 1);
    element.classList.toggle("added");
    element.classList.toggle('img-effect')
  }
}
var timer
const createSlider = () => {
  // check slider image length
  if (sliders.length < 2) {
    alert('Select at least 2 image.')
    return;
  }
  // crate slider previous next area
  sliderContainer.innerHTML = '';
  const prevNext = document.createElement('div');
  prevNext.className = "prev-next d-flex w-100 justify-content-between align-items-center";
  prevNext.innerHTML = ` 
  <span class="prev" onclick="changeItem(-1)"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
  <span class="next" onclick="changeItem(1)"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
  `;

  sliderContainer.appendChild(prevNext)
  document.querySelector('.main').style.display = 'block';
  // hide image aria
  imagesArea.style.display = 'none';
  let duration = document.getElementById('duration').value || 1000;
  if (duration <= 400) {
    duration = 1000;
    if (confirm("slider duration will set to 1s default")) {
      sliders.forEach(slide => {
        let item = document.createElement('div')
        item.className = "slider-item";
        item.innerHTML = `<img class="w-100"
        src="${slide}"
        alt="">`;
        sliderContainer.appendChild(item)
      })
      changeSlide(0)
      timer = setInterval(sliderMoverCallback, duration);
      lastSetDuration = duration;
    }
    else {
      imagesArea.style.display = 'block';

    }

  }

  else {

    sliders.forEach(slide => {
      let item = document.createElement('div')
      item.className = "slider-item";
      item.innerHTML = `<img class="w-100"
      src="${slide}"
      alt="">`;
      sliderContainer.appendChild(item)
    })
    changeSlide(0)
    timer = setInterval(sliderMoverCallback, duration);
    lastSetDuration = duration;

  }

}

const sliderMoverCallback = () => {
  changeSlide(++slideIndex);
}

// change slider index 
const changeItem = index => {
  changeSlide(slideIndex += index);
}

// change slide item
const changeSlide = (index) => {

  const items = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-item');
  if (index < 0) {
    slideIndex = items.length - 1
    index = slideIndex;
  };

  if (index >= items.length) {
    index = 0;
    slideIndex = 0;
  }

  items.forEach(item => {
    item.style.display = "none"
  })

  items[index].style.display = "block"
}

function getInputValue() {
  document.querySelector('.main').style.display = 'none';
  clearInterval(timer);
  const search = document.getElementById('search');
  getImages(search.value)
  sliders.length = 0;
}

const triggerSearchBtn = inputField.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {

  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    getInputValue();
  }

})

sliderBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  createSlider()
})

sliderContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = undefined;
})

sliderContainer.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  if (timer === undefined) { // if no animation is performing now then start it
    timer = setInterval(sliderMoverCallback, lastSetDuration)
  }
})

//Bonus Marking javascript
const toggleSpinner = () => {
  const spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');
    spinner.classList.toggle('d-flex');
}

const dangerInfo = (show) => {
  const error = document.getElementById('error');

 if (show) {
    error.classList.add('d-flex');
  }
  else {
    error.classList.remove('d-flex');
  }
 
}
```

P.S. I would definitely do some refactoing. Pretty hard to read and find what you need.

Comment: Thanks brother for your kind support. The code worked now. but one little thing! when I copy all of your js file and replace in my work directory then this code didn't work. but when I took some necessary portion and implement in my code then it's worked

Comment: Strange situation. It works perfect in my browser (Google Chrome Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit))